# ANACONDA - I have to type export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:“$PATH” everytime I rerun the terminal

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, python3, anaconda

Whenever I open a terminal, I have to write

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

to use any feature of anaconda

I want a persistent path.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open despite the similarities because this problem is so common to Anaconda that it deserves a separate question for Anaconda users.

Comment: Also I don't think it would be a good idea to merge the two questions because that would require deleting Klaus-Dieter Warzecha's answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the file .bashrc (hidden file), located in the home directory, runs codes every time a new terminal is opened.

Then add a line on it:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I'm running Mint and I have this line in my .bashrc. But I note that .bashrc is not run when I start an env console from within anaconda navigator.
I added that line to /etc/bash.bashrc and it worked (single user system)

Comment: it worked on my ubuntu 18.04 LTS, thanks @Vitor

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it be nice if somebody else would handle that for you? ;-)

Edit your `.profile` and add something like the following lines:

```
if [ -d "$HOME/anaconda3/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: What does the if statement with the -d indicate here?

Comment: @Rik Square brackets with -d  are used to test if the string is  a directory.

Answer (score 3):

Start with:

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

go down to the last line in the file and add

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and then <kbd>enter</kbd>

open a new terminal and enjoy anaconda--navigator

Comment: this worked on ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Anaconda3

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall anaconda, and notice that at the end of the install process there is a optional selection that allow you to add conda command to your PATH.

You can choose to say yes, and then you can use the command `conda`.